# Is there a Elasticsearch plugin similar to the Solr analysis tool?

Tags: solr, elasticsearch, analysis

Solr has the built-in ["Analysis Screen"](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Analysis+Screen), which helps to debug the interplay between tokenizers and filters for specific field types:

[image]

Is there a plugin for ElasticSearch that does something similar? Specifically, I want to see the input/ output of each filter, not only the end result of the analysis chain. I used Google quite intensively on this, but didn't find anything.

https://www.found.no/play/#analysis contains exactly the feature I want (scroll down to "myAnalyzer"), but unfortunately it's not something I can run on my index. But it shows that such a feature is possible.

Edit: I know there are many plugins that show me the output for a complete chain of filters, for example kopf as suggested by user @Bass:

[image]

**This is not what I want!** I want to see the output of each filter, not only the end result.

Comment: It may help you http://siddhumehta.blogspot.in/2014/05/elasticsearch-tutorial-elasticsearch-gui-tools.html

Comment: http://www.elasticsearch.org/overview/kibana/installation/

Comment: are you asking Elasticsearch UI?

Comment: Please try to understand the question before commenting. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one standalone tool called [elyzer](https://github.com/o19s/elyzer/) made by the nice folks at OpenSource Connections. That tool will show you the state of your tokens at any step (char filter, tokenizer, token filter) of the analysis process and it is very simple to use.

Installing it is very simple via `pip install elyzer` and then you can use it as a command-line tool, e.g.

```
$ elyzer --es "http://localhost:9200" --index tmdb --analyzer english_bigrams --text "Mary had a little lamb"
TOKENIZER: standard
{1:Mary}    {2:had} {3:a}   {4:little}  {5:lamb}    
TOKEN_FILTER: standard
{1:Mary}    {2:had} {3:a}   {4:little}  {5:lamb}    
TOKEN_FILTER: lowercase
{1:mary}    {2:had} {3:a}   {4:little}  {5:lamb}    
TOKEN_FILTER: porter_stem
{1:mari}    {2:had} {3:a}   {4:littl}   {5:lamb}    
TOKEN_FILTER: bigram_filter
{1:mari had}    {2:had a}   {3:a littl} {4:littl lamb}
```

Comment: It seems its not updated anymore and should fail with newer versions of ES because of [this issue](https://github.com/o19s/elyzer/issues/22)

Comment: @Suzana elyzer inspired me another tool I wrote which does pretty much the same + a few other things, you can check it out here: https://github.com/consulthys/ElastiXray

Answer (score 1):

I've used [Inquisitor](https://github.com/polyfractal/elasticsearch-inquisitor) in the past to test out tokenizers and filters.  It sits on top of the Elasticsearch analyze API and can be used from a web front end.

You should also try another plugin called [elasticsearch-extended-analyze](https://github.com/johtani/elasticsearch-extended-analyze) which returns the same token-level information as the Solr analysis page (though without the web front end).

Answer (score 0):

[Analyze API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html) can be used to test the analyzers. It is not so pretty but does the job.

Example

```
GET localhost:9200/_analyze
{
  "tokenizer" : "keyword",
  "token_filters" : ["lowercase"],
  "char_filters" : ["html_strip"],
  "text" : "this is a <b>test</b>"
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Yes ,We can do it by Elasticsearch - kopf.Elastic Search-KOPF is administrator Tools. U will type this command in you command prompt

bin/plugin --install lmenezes/elasticsearch-kopf/1.1

please let me know, if you have any doubt?

Comment: Maybe my question was formulated not clear enough, but this is definitely not an answer to my question.

I know the kopf plugin, and it only shows me the output of a complete analyzer (see my edit above).

Comment: wait i will check and Tell u @Martin

Comment: It's called Cerebro now but even the newest version only shows the end result of the analysis chain, not the steps in between.